# Setting Date in Ionic Datepicker - Only Days changed and not the Month - Using (ngModelChange)

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, ionic5

I have two date input, Start Date and End Date.

I have made the start date by default [(ngModel)]="defaultStartDate" in template and in TS I set it for today's date;
`defaultStartDate =  new Date().toISOString();`

For the End Date, I have set by default [(ngModel)]="defaultEndDate" the date to be **+1** of the **defaultStartDate**;
`defaultEndDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1)).toISOString();`

So for example today's date is 27-10-2020,
Start Date : 27 October 2020
End Date : 28 October 2020

So I would like to make the End Date dynamic by changing the min value and also sets the default by +1 day.

Here's my template.page.html:

```
<ion-col>
    <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="defaultStartDate"
     ngModel name="startDate"
     displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY"
     [min]="defaultStartDate"
     (ngModelChange)="setMinEndDate()"
     placeholder="Start Date"
     ></ion-datetime>
</ion-col>
<ion-col>
     <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="defaultEndDate"
      ngModel name="endDate"
      displayFormat="DD MMMM YYYY"
      [min]="defaultEndDate"
      placeholder="End Date"
     ></ion-datetime>
</ion-col>
```

So in my date.page.ts:

```
startDate =  new Date().toISOString();
defaultEndDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate()+1)).toISOString();

setMinEndDate() {
    let selected = new Date(this.startDate);
    console.log(selected)
    let newEndDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(selected.getDate()+1));
    this.defaultEndDate = newEndDate.toISOString();
  }
```

**The Problem**
Everything works well until I want to change the month.
For example, if I pick 28 November 2020, the End date change to 29 **October** 2020 instead of 29 November 2020.

Where could be the problem. Anyone have any solution/brief explaination? I am new to Ionic hence apology for this issue.